# Google Tag Manager not firing where as it was previously

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've have a website where I configured Google Tag manager. ALl the tags were firing okay on page load and clicks events.

I then started to rename some of tags and triggers and file them in particular folders so they are neat. Now when I go to preview mode in tag manager, none of my tags fire where as they did previously. I've double checked my configuration tag and I have the correct measurement ID etc but just doesn't work.

What surprisingly does work are the events in summary bit in tag manager, so the standard events like scroll depth, window loaded etc seem to register.

I have no blocking triggers on any of my tags. I've also tried to restore my tags to a previous version but that's not helped at all.

Any ideas what else I could check? I think what could have broke the system was me renaming the configuration tag. I've now created another configuration tag and set it to fire on all pages but this does not fire when I navigate around the site. Is there anything else I could check?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't complete your debugging and you failed to mention what kind of tags stopped working: GA4 or GA UA.

Using the GTM preview, fire a trigger, select it, see if your tag fired. If it didn't, find it in the list while having the trigger selected, select the tag, it will show the tag view and report on what triggers did not fire.

If this is not enough, then add debugging screenshots to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I have GA4 and GA UA tags both on the page and both have stopped working. I've been solely working on the GA4 tags and triggers. I've found a blog post which I'm going to work through which highlights why tagmanager in preview may not be working.

Comment: Make sure the GTM ID on page is the same as the one you're using for preview. That's the most common preview issue.

Comment: Last night I deleted all the new GA4 tags and triggers I created in the last week. I've logged in this morning and my tags for GA UA are now firing again (I haven't changed GTM tag in my code). I'm going to individually add the GA4 tags now (which  were working previously 10 days ago until I did something on Monday). I think I may have broken it when I was trying to exclude internal traffic, will go slower this time around.